# In Angular: http post method, how to pass body and header that has 'Basic Auth' with 'Username' and 'Password'

Tags: angular

I have implemented oath in spring boot and with the POSTMAN, login services are working fine as expected(generating token) using following parameters

In Postman:
  In Body:

```
selected: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

**Key & Value**

```
grant_type : password
username : app123
password : app@123
```

**Authorization:**

selected : Basic Auth

Uasename : appsec

Password : secpass

This works fine, But when trying from angular it is not working.

I tried by using 'const' and setting 'var'

**1)**

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers : new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Username':'appsec','Password':'secpass'})
};

export class AuthenticationService {

  login(username: string, password: string, grant_type:"password") {

    return this.http.post<any>(`http://localhost:9191/oauth/token`, { username, password, grant_type} ,{ headers:httpOptions})

}
```

**2)**

```
login(username: string, password: string, grant_type:string) {

    var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({'context-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Basic Auth':'True','Username':'appsec','Password':'secpass'});

    return this.http.post<any>(`http://localhost:9191/oauth/token`, { username, password, grant_type} ,{ headers:reqHeader})
}
```

in the Header section the error is

```
reqHeader = HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
```

Comment: Which version of angular are you using? And do you use HttpClient or Http?

Comment: Angular 7 and HttpClient.

Answer (score 2):

1) Wtih 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', you have to send stringyfied body :

```
 const body = JSON.stringify({username: userName, password: password, grant_type:grant_type });
```

2) To check headers in console, try hitting this :

```
req.headers.keys();
```

Cheers (y)

Answer (score 0):

In the Headers:

```
var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({'context-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Basic Auth':'True','Username':'appsec','Password':'secpass'});
```

Please Try:

```
var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Basic Auth':'True','Username':'appsec','Password':'secpass'});
```

Since:
'context-type' is not a valid header

Also I don't know why you are setting the user credentials in header as well as in the body, Setting credentials (username, password, grant) in Body will be sufficient

Comment: In PostMan for 'Basic Auth' I need to pass Username and Password(client_id and password). The other one is for login users -> username and password.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `Authorization` as Basic Auth in HttpHeaders.

```
new HttpHeaders({
 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 'Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('appsec:secpass')
})
```